# Can I embed a whole website in my wordpress site so that it shows in a lightbox?

Tags: wordpress, embed, lightbox

I sometimes embed full websites in my wordpress site, with this code:

```
<object data="https://skiplagged.com/" width="100%" height="600px">
    <embed src="https://skiplagged.com/" width="100%″" height="600px" />
</object>
```

It works fine, but I would like the website to open up in a lightbox - does anyone know if that is possible at all, and how to do it?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

add this in your theme functions.php and make sure to have correct fancybox js and script source

```
function load_fancybox_script() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yoursite.com/fancyboxdirectory/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yoursite.com/fancyboxdirectory/source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
( function($) {
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("a.fancybox-iframe").fancybox();
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head','load_fancybox_script', 99);
```

Then to have a pop-up

```
<a class="fancybox-iframe" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="https://skiplagged.com/">Iframe</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've never used jquery but I'm definitely giving it a try!